Should I refinish high-traffic areas of a hardwood floor only or the whole floor?
Need to refinish our hardwood floor. Do you think we should only sand the high-traffic areas that look bad or the whole floor? Only high-traffic areas look bad. Other areas look new because they were under rugs and furniture like selection couches.
We will hire a pro to do it but also want to ask others' advice. Please see the link for the floor images.
https://imgur.com/a/Dz9oURb

Probably a pro for the sanding at least.  Some of those floor sanders will sand down to China if you do not watch them, some are more user friendly.

Do the whole floor.
Trying to match edges to join seamlessly is a no hoper.
